# Laravel 5.4 app.js code obfuscation

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, webpack, obfuscation

I would like to know how to obtain my Laravel *public/js/app.js* code obfuscated just like the one in the Laravel repo (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/js/app.js).

When I run **npm run production** command, it gets minified, but not obfuscated...
How can be obfuscation performed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your patch version of Laravel? I've just tried it with Laravel 5.4.6 and I've got same similar output as one in the repo... Note: that there might have been few more changes across version; especially in laravel-mix.

Comment: Thanks Ivo. I found I had an error in webpack.mix.js file. Everything is fine now. By the way, can you confirm that the obfuscated code is protected against a malicious client who wanted to copy it?? (I have some bussiness logic there, and I do not want to share it with my competence... :S

Comment: I'd say hardly. Obfuscated working javascript, is still valid and working javascript.

Comment: Thanks again, I will dig into it.

Comment: Hi,
Regarding obfuscating your code, as Ivo mentioned it's still valid and works.
I've started using Jscrambler. I had looked at some obfuscators, and found they were easy to deobfuscate, but  Jscrambler offers a series of transformations. I like the self defending, and the date locks they have. It's good to send demos as you can set a time period for your app to work. They have a bunch of other transformations but the date locks were the selling point for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot ;)

Answer (score 0):

People are also having issues with "Mix" in terms of OS compatibility I'm still trying to figure this one out. Cheers m8

[Laravel 5.4 Mix in c9.io ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943909/laravel-5-4-mix-in-c9-io-ide)