# Laravel 5.4 Mix in c9.io ide

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I've been trying to get Laravel Mix NodeJS compiling scripts to run in the c9 ide for hours now hopefully someone has a explanation or a fix.

So basically I'm trying to compile my sass and a javascript file which both are default so there is no possibility of errors within the code. My webpack.mix.js is default and well and all I'm trying to do is run the npm command "npm run dev" which compiles the files without uglifying it and such. "npm run watch" which auto compiles every time you save and a change has been made does not work as well. Sorry for the terriable explanation but I'm just looking for a quick fix.

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated by a c9.io pro!

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. The issue was caused because c9 by default was running an older version of node <--- so a simple update to node 7 fixed the issue.